# Discussion "LastReplyBy" with SharePoint REST

Tags: rest, sharepoint

Anyone knows how to get the "Last Reply By" of a discussion thread from REST?
I use:

```
_api/web/lists/getByTitle('NL Management Discussion')/items?$expand=Author,Folder&$select=ID,Title,Modified,Author/Title,DiscussionLastUpdated,Folder/ItemCount,Folder/LastReplyBy&$top=5000&$filter=startswith(ContentTypeId,
```

It does not error but there is no 'LastReplyBy' in the folder's values. The Item count does show.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the REST API below to get 'LastReplyBy'.

```
_api/web/lists/getByTitle('NL%20Management%20Discussion')/items?$expand=Author,Folder,LastReplyBy&$select=ID,Title,Modified,Author/Title,LastReplyBy/Title,DiscussionLastUpdated,Folder/ItemCount&$top=5000&$filter=ContentType eq 'Discussion'
```

[image]

Comment: So "LastReplyBy" is like author and folder. good to know. thank you much

Comment: Yes, the "LastReplyBy" is a user field.